# J2EE Application with Netbeans and Glassfish (No [EntityType] was found)

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, ejb-3.0

I'm using NetBeans IDE 7.0.1 and Glassfish 3.0.1.

I'm building a J2EE application with JPA + EJB3.0 + JSF2.0 and when I try to deploy my project I got this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No [EntityType] was found for the key class [objetmetier.Application] in the Metamodel - please verify that the [Entity] class was referenced in persistence.xml using a specific <class>objetmetier.Application</class> property or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element
```

For me it's a problem of EJB3.0 deployment on the glassfish server. But I don't understand, because they are deployed in the server when I look in the glassfish admin console.

Comment: Does your persistence.xml contain the specific class or the `exclude-unlisted-classes` attribute?

Comment: Yes Matt. The persistence.xml is ok, because I try the solution to upgrate netbeans and now it's working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I,
I have been resolved this problem this year during studies : you just should update your netbeans at version 7.1.0.
There is a incompactibility with yours version of glassfish and Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the problem is the management of EJB 3.1 with NetBeans 7.0.1. The EJB can't be deployed correctly on the Glassfish Server.